# Where to find old versions of bitcoin-qt from 2011-2012

Tags: bitcoin-core

Where to find old versions of bitcoin-qt from 2011-2012 for download? I cannot find anything on the source code repository and all links I've found on forums are dead.

Is anyone able to assist finding the very old windows bitcoin-qt downloads?

Comment: Preemptively, you don't need an old version of the software to open an old wallet; it would be unwise to use any of the extremely old Bitcoin versions.

Comment: I want to analyse see how the random seed was generated in old versions, mainly the UI part, I don't plan on opening any wallets or doing any transactions.

Comment: @rolls Perhaps it is more interesting to ask directly how keys were generated in old versions of Bitcoin-Qt? A good answer would include references to source code to support its claims.

Comment: I want the actual release so I can see the UI for generating and saving the random seed. So I can assist with the off chance it is recoverable. I can't find any examples of what the random seed data (from moving your mouse) looked like.

Comment: Before Bitcoin Core 0.13 there was no concept of a "random seed", as wallets weren't deterministic. Keys were just generated randomly, each individually, and added to a keypool. In old versions, OpenSSL's random number generator was used. You need to look at the source code for this, I don't think you can easily derive this from looking at the binary.

Comment: That is what I suspected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the first release of bitcoin on this old bitcointalk thread offered by Hal Finney himself https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=68121.0

For the more recent version, circa 2009 you can dig the official github repo releases https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/releases

Comment: The releases on github do not have binaries.

Comment: These must be compiled, compiling qt on windows is not trivial even for a developer unfamiliar with it.

Comment: @rolls: Do you need to compile? Can't  source inspection be used to "see how the random seed was generated "?

Comment: The source code is happily all in the same source tree for every version since 0.1. None of the versions you're talking about used HD seeds though, they used raw private keys.

Comment: I want to see how the random seed was displayed, if there was a prompt to back it up and if so what the random data looked like, eg how many bytes, base64 etc. I remember being prompted to move a mouse around the screen to generate seed data.

Comment: You say they used raw private keys, how were the private keys generated then? They must have had a random seed from somewhere, from memory you generated the seed data from moving your mouse around the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I have a copy of the Windows 32-bit version 0.4.0 of the Bitcoin client (from 2011), install .exe file.  If you want a copy, let me know.